# Proper input of complex ConvertFrom-Json webrequest

Tags: json, powershell

I have a complex webrequest with json within, which I need to call correct:

```
$variable = ((invoke-webrequest $OctopusURL//api/tenants/$TenantID/variables -Headers $header).content | ConvertFrom-Json).ProjectVariables.Projects-246.variables.Environments-101.f7866b87-e194-4a90-adbe-a4eae705ef86
```

Unfortunately, it falls with error after "-" symbol.

http://prntscr.com/jklawn

How properly input all path with "-" symbol within?

Comment: `$variable = ((invoke-webrequest $OctopusURL//api/tenants/$TenantID/variables -Headers $header).content | ConvertFrom-Json).ProjectVariables."Projects-246".variables."Environments-101"."f7866b87-e194-4a90-adbe-a4eae705ef86"`?

Comment: Does it help of you enclose the problematic parameters name in quotes?  For example: `(...).ProjectVariables."Projects-246".variables."Environments-101"."f7866b87-e194-4a90-adbe-a4eae705ef86"`

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh and boxdog - thank you both for your answers - it works!